# Windows Phone 8 Button color while pressed

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am pretty new to Windows Phone, XAML and such and I am trying to solve this. I have custom colored button, but while this button is pressed it changes its color. How to customize this "pressed" color/properties? Is there any simple way that I missed? I was searching over the internet but nothing helped.

Comment: please show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know about styles, states and many other stuff, it's simple but you need to learn, you can go through this sample code from MSDN to create a [Windows Phone Custom Style Button](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Windows-Phone-Custom-Style-b48d528a)